# Merge Multiple File Choosers to One Multi-File Chooser and Upload Sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, file-upload

hopefully this problem has an easy solution.

I need to upload files one at a time to my server, so I have a script that works by queuing a file upload through an iframe for each file input field.

Right now, I have a working script that loops through and uploads each file individually, chosen with:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

And looping like this:

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
```

**My question is**, how can I change the *.each* to work with this, just one file chooser:

```
<input type="file" name="file" mulitple/>

$(???).each(function(){
```

---

I have tried

```
fileInput = document.getElementById("multiFileChooser");
$(fileInput.files).each(function(){
```

But the file is not sent nor is present in the payload for the request.

**Edit 2:**

---

Fixed and working solution:

```
(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){         //on button press
        for(var ii = 0; ii < $('#multiChoose').get(0).files.length; ii++){
            sendFile($('#multiChoose').get(0).files[ii]);
            //wait until upload complete to start next one
        }
    }); 
})})(jQuery); 

function sendFile(file) {
        var uri = "upload.php";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();

        xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //queue next file
        };
        fd.append('file', file);

        xhr.send(fd);
    }
```

Comment: You aren't showing any code where a form is submitted.  Please show ALL of your code.

Comment: [Pretty much everything you need to know is in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). Also, to directly answer your question, `$('#multiFileChooser').get(0).files[0];` contains a list of file objects, where you can access information about each of them.

Comment: Hello @ohgodwhy, thank you for the reply. I am still having problems uploading the file. If I set 's.file' to `$('#multiFileChooser').get(0)` then all of the files are passed to PHP at once multiple times successfully. In the code I put in the edit, I try to pass each file individually with the loop, the request is made but the file is not attached and uploaded properly.

Comment: I got it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction